# UIView scale animation overshoots when changed

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewanimation

When I animate a change to a view's transform, then reset that change in another animation before the first animation finishes, everything's great (shown here with a rotation). The animation smoothly switches to the new target:

[image]

But when I do this with a scale, the animation overshoots magnificently:

[image]

Here's the breaking code:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1) {
    self.someView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.001, 0.001, 1)
}
UIView.animateWithDuration(1,
    delay: 0.5,
    options: nil,
    animations: {
        self.someView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    }, completion: nil
)
```

Has anyone else seen this? Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: And is there a good workaround?

EDIT 2: I believe this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543763/animate-transform-scale-with-uiviewanimationoptionbeginfromcurrentstate-not-work) and am voting to close.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animate transform.scale with UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543763/animate-transform-scale-with-uiviewanimationoptionbeginfromcurrentstate-not-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This blog post](http://iosoteric.com/additive-animations-animatewithduration-in-ios-8/) provides the answer: in iOS 8, UIView animations are additive, and this has an unfortunate result with scale animations.

Basically, the second animation happens *together with* the first animation. The only solution is to explicitly remove the original animation before starting a new one:

```
view.layer.transform = view.layer.presentationLayer().transform
view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm not quite sure what your looking for but if you want the view to go back to it's original scale you'd add the .Autoreverse flag.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0, options: .Autoreverse | .Repeat, animations: {
       myView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.001, 0.001, 1)
    }, completion: nil)
```

While if you wanted to string animations together I'd do it within UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration()

```
UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(2, delay: 0.0, options: nil, animations: {

        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.0, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            // Animation 1
        })

        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(1, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            // Animation 2
        })

    }, completion: nil)
```

[image: Animation Gif]

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear. In the actual app, the user performs some action that should stop the original animation and return it to its original state. The UIViewAnimationOptions.BeginFromCurrentState flag doesn't seem to have any effect either.